# svg brightness filter in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, svg-filters

I need to convert the following `svg` filter (since I cannot rely on pure `css` filter)

```
<filter id="brightness">
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="linear" slope="2"/>
    <feFuncG type="linear" slope="2"/>
    <feFuncB type="linear" slope="2"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

in `D3` code. But the code below ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hapmq81L/) here) does not work:

```
const svg = d3.select("svg")

var filter = svg.append("defs")
.attr("id", "brightness")
.append("feComponentTransfer")
filter.append("feFuncR").attr("type","linear").attr("slope","2");
filter.append("feFuncG").attr("type","linear").attr("slope","2");
filter.append("feFuncB").attr("type","linear").attr("slope","2");

var circle=svg.append("circle")
.attr("cx",100)
.attr("cy",100)
.attr("r",100)
.attr("fill","red")
.style("fill", "url(#brightness)");
```

Maybe the two last lines conflict. How can I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're putting the id on the defs element, not the filter.
2. You don't actually have a filter element
3. You're specifying the filter on the circle using fill rather than filter.

Once you've fixed all that you'd get this...

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
    
        var filter = svg.append("defs")
         .append("filter")
        .attr("id", "brightness")
        .append("feComponentTransfer")
    filter.append("feFuncR").attr("type","linear").attr("slope","2");
        filter.append("feFuncG").attr("type","linear").attr("slope","2");
    filter.append("feFuncB").attr("type","linear").attr("slope","2");
    
    var circle=svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx",100)
    .attr("cy",100)
    .attr("r",100)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("filter", "url(#brightness)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```